# WSO2BPS 3.6.0 BPEL HT task assignment / authorization

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

along the process we have a human task, though I have issue to assign it. At the current state it's ok to assign it to any user (Internal/everybody).

For the HT I have following configuration:

```
<htd:logicalPeopleGroups>
    <htd:logicalPeopleGroup name="everybody">
        <htd:documentation xml:lang="en-US">
            Everybody
        </htd:documentation>
        <htd:parameter name="role" type="xsd:string" />
    </htd:logicalPeopleGroup>
</htd:logicalPeopleGroups>

<htd:peopleAssignments>
    <htd:potentialOwners>
        <htd:from logicalPeopleGroup="everybody">
            <htd:argument name="role">
                Internal/everyone
            </htd:argument>
        </htd:from>
    </htd:potentialOwners>
</htd:peopleAssignments>
```

which works well on the local environment (local userstore accessed as an admin user).

However - deployed on the server with AD authentication, I am unable to access the created tasks.

In the humantask-explorer I can see the tasks as "Claimable", but not as "My Tasks". Trying to open the task the I got a message

> Access Denied. You are not authorized to perform this task

and the wso2carbon.log claims

```
ID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-18 11:05:28,100] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.api.client.TaskOperationsImpl} -  org
.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.runtime.api.HumanTaskIllegalAccessException: Access Denied. You are not authorized
 to perform this task {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.api.client.TaskOperationsImpl}
TID: [-1234] [] [ 11:05:28,592] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.commands.Claim} -  The user[ex
t-admin] cannot perform [GetInput] operation as either he is in EXCLUDED_OWNERS role or he is not in task roles
[[ACTUAL_OWNER, POTENTIAL_OWNERS, BUSINESS_ADMINISTRATORS, STAKEHOLDERS, TASK_INITIATOR, NOTIFICATION_RECIPIENTS]] {o
rg.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.engine.commands.Claim}
```

Thank you all for any hint

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your LDAP. The user ext-admin has to be un internal/everyone group for him to be able to work with that task.